# Still paying for a deleted VM

Tags: azure, resources, virtual-machine

I am just exploring Azure and I made a Virtual Machine using the portal and I deleted that after two hours or something. 
In my cost management I can see that I am still paying for that resource group that contained components of the Virtual Machine, it is been a week since I deleted it.
I am still paying for that resource group even though I can't see it in my resource groups, neither on the portal nor on Powershell.

Is this a common issue?

Comment: Hope you have removed all the components related to VM. (DISK and other network services)

Comment: Are costs adding up? It might just be the costs for running it for two hours. The next billing period it should not be listened.

Comment: you should talk to support about billing. billing support is free. but if you deleted all the resources related to vm or deleted the resource group - you are not getting billed for those (unless there is some bug with your resources)

Comment: @MohamedInfaaz  Yes, I deleted the entire resource group with its component, the resource group was to contain the VM and after I was done, I deleted altogether. If they are not deleted, I should be able to see them in my resources list, right? But what I see is two resource group, one is for powershell and the other one is just a test resource group for a blob storage and I can see in my Cost analysis that it has not cost a dime so far!

Comment: @PeterBons Yes the costs are adding up, last Thursday it was about 2-3 dollars, and today it doubled up!

Comment: Please follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/find-unattached-disks) to find and remove all the undeleted attached disks.

Comment: Unmanaged disks(VHD files)  are stored in the blob storage, you should check if it's deleted.

Comment: @IvanYang Fortunately or unfortunately I dont have a blob storage yet, it is just a storage account that sits in my resources, and it was made a day after deletion of VM and its component.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/find-unattached-disks), I suggest you check if all disks attached to the vm are not deleted.

For managed disk, please follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/find-unattached-disks#managed-disks-find-and-delete-unattached-disks) to find and delete them.

For Unmanaged disks(the vhd files stored in azure blob storage), please follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/find-unattached-disks#unmanaged-disks-find-and-delete-unattached-disks) to find and delete them.

Delete any [orphaned Network Interface Cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/find-unattached-nics) (NIC) and Public IPs that were associated with the VM. They are billed even when the VM is deleted.

**Update:**

run powershell in azure portal:

[image]

Comment: This should be typed in Azure Powershell? Then I get some errors!

Comment: Well, I wrote the whole code in one or two line, since you cant write the way it stands on the webpage, and it gives me errors for `)` of even for `in` expression in foreach loop and `$managedDisks` gets an error saying it is unexpected token

Comment: You mean in powershell or in azure portal?

Comment: I use the powershell on the portal, isnt that Azure Powershell?

Comment: Hi, you can write the powershell like this in the azure portal cloudshell, see my updated section in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ivan. I have done that now but nothing happens after I run the command, should I be expecting something on the screen?

Comment: @user10801035, sorry for late response, I'm just back to company. Yes, if you have some disks which are not deleted, you should see some output in the output screen(since we use write-output in the powershell script). And if it does not work for you, I suggest you should submit a support ticket then you can get help from the azure support team, follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). Hope it can help you.

Comment: @user10801035, added the delete NIC section, you can see if it can help you.